# Vlookup /w text replacement

Tags: microsoft-excel, vlookup

I have an issue I can't figure out. I need to see if two numbers match and the replace with a following cell.

So here is the example:
If Col `G` matches Col `L` Replace `D` /w Col `M`. I am using

```
=VLOOKUP(G:G,L:L,M:M=FALSE)
```

I know I'm doing it wrong but I dunno what else to do

https://ibb.co/QjNmsJT

Comment: You can't look up an entire column's value...I think you want to put this in `D2` and drag down: `=VLOOKUP(G2,L:M,2,False)`?

Comment: No I get n/a :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can. You just have some errors in your syntax.
[image: Here ya go]

Commas separate arguments and colons define ranges.

```
=VLOOKUP
```

is the function you're using

```
G:G
```

is the source field - the value you want to look FOR

```
L:M
```

is the range to search.

```
2
```

is the column to bring back - this is relative to the range you defined in the previous argument, 1 being the first column. We want the value in the second column (`M`) of the given range (`L:M`)

```
FALSE
```

means you want to restrict your search of column L to exact matches (in the example shown, assuming column L was ordered numerically, for example the order 24 would return return STOCKTON as the value for ORDER_CHK 25, which is the next one closest to the search term. If this doesn't make sense, don't worry about it too much, it's uncommon to set this to TRUE except for very specific use cases).

Separate each of those arguments with commas (as shown in screenshot).

If this isn't working, post more information as to what you're seeing when you try it.

If you're getting #N/A's all the way down, are there actually any values that match? There don't appear to be any in your screenshot.

**EDIT** per suggestion in comment. In this use case there is no functional difference between

```
=VLOOKUP(G:G,L:M,2,FALSE)
```

and

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,L:M,2,FALSE)
```

or even

```
=VLOOKUP(G2,$L$2:$M$9999,2,FALSE)
```

**Any of those formulas, dragged or copied down in column D, will work equally well.**

The reason to use a full column reference ('G:G' and 'L:M') rather than a named or used range (G2,$L$2:$M$9999 or even naming a range via name manager) is that it makes the formula easier to write and maintain (don't have to worry about updating ranges if the size/shape of data changes). Once you start dealing with extremely large sets of data and operating with more advanced functions, though, this can slow down your performance since you're asking Excel to examine more data.

It's extremely unlikely to make any appreciable difference with a simple VLOOKUP, which is why I tend to default to writing such formulas with full column references. But if you're doing, say, SUMPRODUCT operations on array formulas, you probably want to manually limit your used ranges. Again, for this use case the simpler approach (or whatever makes sense to you as the user) is probably better.

Comment: Can you perhaps explain what the benefits of doing it lije this are vs. VLOOKUP(G2,L:M,2,FALSE) dragged down?

Comment: Thanks, upvoted, you learn something new each day.

Comment: I am hitting a wall :-/ I run the formula and I am getting n/a but I know there are matches I can do a duplicate finder and see them,

Comment: Copy your worksheet. Eliminate all or almost all the data excepting at least one matching record. Enter the formula that should work. Show the result. Screenshot. Edit this new information of what you've tried and isn't working into your question**. Comment again so I know to check back. In other words, start troubleshooting via simplication. It could be any of a number of things that are hard to diagnose without any information. ** I'm not familiar enough with the norms of Stack Exchange to know if you're supposed to ask that as a new question or what; if you are,  do what's appropriate